# Is there a general term for minimum, median, maximum, mean, quartiles, etc

Tags: terminology

I'm looking to be able to say something more brief than "this tool collects the minimum, median, mean, maximum, and quartiles" of a distribution.

Comment: Summary statistics

Comment: @SmallChess: that's an answer right there. Want to post it as such?

Comment: @SmallChess is correct. Also note that all except the mean are [tag:order-statistics].

Comment: Apart from the mean I think some people call them Tukey's five number summary but I cannot find a reference for this.

Comment: @mdewey the Wikipedia article on the [five number summary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five-number_summary) offers a reference.

Comment: It's not quite true that median and quartiles are order statistics as often they are interpolated. All, including the mean, are defined once the order statistics are known (given recipes for median and quartiles; there are several recipes for quartiles).